# Android Studio using old versions of gradle libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm dealing with a really odd issue with an old project. I changed the camera library used in the project and that library was using an updated version of google maps. Previously we were using 7.5.0 but since the camera library was using 17.0.0 I updated the project's google maps library to 17.0.0 as well.

Running the app works fine, and even making a production apk works. But if I try to build a debug version (without signing anything) I get this error :
`` Interface `com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi(classpath class)` used as super class of `com.google.android.gms.location.places.internal.zzd`. ``

A little more details here:

`Failed to transform artifact 'play-services-location.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.`

Again, this is odd because there is no 7.5.0 anywhere in the app anymore. It makes me think that Android Studio is trying to use a cached version.

Similarily if I try to run the gradle dependencies command to check on what's going on I get another odd error:

`Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 4.10.3. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /appName/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.4.1-all.zip`

Meanwhile that IS the version I have as my distributionUrl , which again makes me think Android Studio is trying to use a cached version.
I've tried cleaning/invalidating caches and restarting. I even restarted my computer. Nothing has worked yet

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to delete **.gradle** folder in the application path.
It will caused Android Studio fetch data again and in this scenario you will be sure that no cache files will be used.

also please check gradle-wrapper.propertise for you second issue to be same as below:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

hope you problem will solved.

Comment: Didn't work. I deleted the .gradle folder and now I only see the 5.4.1 folder but I still get those errors.

As I said above. I already have:
```distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip```
in my gradle-wrapper.properties

Comment: can you check the content of .gradle folder? Do you see the 5.4.1 folder or not ?
also you can check .idea folder and remove cache files from there.
Maybe deleting build folder in app directory can be an alternative.

Comment: Yeah, 5.4.1 is the only folder there. And I deleted .idea cache folder and deleted the build folder and still getting same issues.